# List element should display exactly 5 items

Tags: css

I have a list containing 100 elements, but I only want to display 5 elements at once with a vertical scrollbar. The `<li>` doesn't have a fixed height and can vary according to its contents (which are fetched from database). The problem is I can keep a fixed height of the `<ul>` and it displays 5 items alright, but sometimes when the content in `<li>` spans multiple lines, the last element gets pushed down.

So the question is, is there a way without using javascript/jquery, where height of `<ul>` will always be equal to first 5 contained `<li>` elements.

Comment: What are the exact limits of your list? Can 1,000,000 be possible too?

Comment: For my specific use, the limit of 1000 is sufficient for next few years, but how is this relevant?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not possible with just CSS. A regular scrollbar will only pop up if the height of the `ul` doesn't fit its contents, which only happens if the height is *not* dependent on its children (that have heights unkown at design time).

In addition, scrolling usually is "continuous": you can show parts of an item. You seem to be looking for more "discrete" scrolling: one "tick" down would mean the top `li` is "scrolled" away and the next `li` is added to the bottom.

I think you should be looking for alternatives, either with fixed height `li`s that have scrollbars or a combination of overflow with ellipses and a popover with full text, or some JavaScript solution.

Comment: That's what I thought. However, I'll still clarify my question. "Continuous" scroll is good enough for me. Once the ul's height is fixed to display first 5 items, I need that height to be fixed even after the user scrolls. So, I don't even need the one-tick-scroll which you talked about. I suppose I can just calculate the height of first five items and set that is UL's height using javascript on page load for this particular problem.

Comment: Aye, the continuous scroll is just one problem. Javascript is most likely the easiest, if not the only solution (though there's a small chance a CSS3 module like flexbox may contain a solution).